# How to configure a nested Connection String in an Azure Web App for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, connection-string

I have a nested connection string in my ASP.NET project that looks like this:

```
  "Data": {
    "Default": {
      "ConnectionString":XYZ",
      "ProviderName": "System.Data.SqlClient"
    }
```

How do I add this on my Azure Web App Configuration Settings under ****Connection** Strings** Section and include the nested logic?

I am able to add the setting under **Application Settings** Section by doing the nesting like this
Data__Defaut__ConnectionString, but the same thing does not work when added to the ConnectionString section (where it belongs).

This is my reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common

Answer (score 0):

You can add use `:` in `Configuration` to get connection string.

**Test Result**

[image]

## Test Code

**[You also can download my sample code in github.](https://github.com/Jason446620/nestconfig)**

1. Add `services.AddDbContext<ConfigurationContext>` in `Startup.cs`.

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddDbContext<ConfigurationContext>(options => {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:mysql_ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]);
        });
    }
   ```
2. Create `ConfigurationContext.cs`.

   ```
   public class ConfigurationContext : DbContext
   {
       public ConfigurationContext(DbContextOptions<ConfigurationContext> options)
            : base(options)
       {
       }
       protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
       {
           if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
           {
               IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                          .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
                          .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                          .Build();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. My `appsettings.json`.

   ```
   {
     "Logging": {
     "LogLevel": {
       "Default": "Information",
       "Microsoft": "Warning",
       "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
     }
   },
   "AllowedHosts": "*",
   "Data": {
      "sqlserver_ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Data Source =.;Initial Catalog = MyTestDB;User Id = sa;Password ={your pwd};"
    },
    "mysql_ConnectionStrings": {
       "DefaultConnection": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
    }
   },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Data Source =.;Initial Catalog = MyTestDB;User Id = sa;Password ={your pwd};"
     }
   }
   ```
4. ViewBag in Controller.

   ```
   public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string res = string.Empty;
        if (_dbContext.Database.CanConnect())
        {
            res = "success";
        }
        else {
            res = "failed";
        }
        ViewBag.Res = res;
        return View();
    }
   ```